# QtConcurrent trying to run a function in thread

Tags: c++, qt, concurrency

I have this function in some other included .cc :

```
void MakeMeshStructure(MeshStructureLayers layers,
  Handle_AIS_InteractiveContext theContext,
  Handle_TDocStd_Document aDoc,
  MyMesh & mesh, 
  int detail_vertex,
  double insulation_thickness,
  OpenMesh::VPropHandleT<MyMesh::Scalar> _max_beam_offset)
```

Inside MainWindow I am trying to run this function in a thread:

```
QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(MeshStructure3::MakeMeshStructure,
  layers, 
  myCadFrame->getWidget()->getContext(),
  myController->getDocument()->getOcafDoc(), 
  mesh, 
  detail_vertex, 
  toolBox->insulation_thickness_SpinBox->value(), 
  max_beam_offset_);
```

Compiler says it has too many arguments.

Answer (score 0):

For more than 5 arguements you need to use Boost::bind, see [Using Bound Function Arguments](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qtconcurrentrun.html#details)